# Algorithm - Python - Start at 1 on each 5 numbers passed

Tags: python, algorithm

I've a SQL database table with a field called "Id", on each new Insert to the database this field Id will autoincrement +1.

I've another field called "FakeId", where I must to restart to 1 on each 5 numbers passed.

Example:

```
Id, FakeId
 1, 1
 2, 2
 3, 3
 4, 4
 5, 5
 6, 1
 7, 2
 8, 3
 9, 4
10, 5
11, 1
12, 2
13, 3
14, 4
15, 5
.., .
```

My knowledge of algorithms is almost non existent.

Can someone show me the way to achieve a formula that will give me the "FakeId"?

Best Regards,

Comment: `((Id - 1) % 5) + 1`

Comment: Hi Tristan, this is the right answer